# ExtJS4 : Rowediting

Tags: extjs, grid, row, editing

Currently I have some columns in my Grid, which are given a value on the server. (update_datetime for instance).
When I update a row on the client, the columns which are assigned a value on the server are not updated (they remain as is).
Is there a way (which does not require a reload of the entire store) to incorporate the changes ?
The result from the server does give back all the latest column details.

--I'm a bit new to extjs, so I think it's a pretty basic question.

Comment: are you running sync on the store or is the store auto syncing?

Comment: I'm running sync in the edit function. On success I can do a e.store.load() which refreshes the entire grid. But I only want to reflect all changes for the edited row (which the DB returned)

Comment: Could I use the response object in some way to update the row?

Comment: Anyone able to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to sync the store with server with StoreWriter.

This link might be useful to you -

[Updating database with Ext Store Writer - ExtJS 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549445/updating-database-with-ext-store-writer-extjs-4-2)